# SQL Server Authentication based Issue , simultaneously ask to reset the password

Tags: sql-server

The database started acting up around 2 months back. Initially the problem was weekly i.e. every Sunday the user passwords would reset and someone had to manual set the password of the database for all the applications to work, as the apps connected to the database would go on hold because of the password reset or expiration.

After 3 weeks the problem started on a daily basis and eventually it started to happen twice or thrice a day, where the passwords would reset or expire and then we need to set them up again.

In the beginning we assumed that a new application installation is causing the problem but that was not the case because when we reset the database and refreshed everything, removing all the instance, new instances appeared automatically after a clean start, namely 'wwo' etc.

So now we assume that the problem has emerged because of those users being created and the unauthorized access to the server and probably the wrong password is being entered using a virus or Trojan thus after multiple wrong password entries made to access the database it expires or resets the password. Our Symantec antivirus did not detect anything. We need help with this problem.

Comment: You're talking about database users, not AD? If that's the case, you should be able to find out who changed the password from transaction log in master, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56930/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-who-changed-the-password-for-a-login There is also a link there for how to track password changes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a CRON that resets the passwords.

Did anyone add a script that was first executed on Sundays, then changed this to be executed daily, then twice/thrice a day ?
You may want to check this script and remove the part that resets the passwords.